# Error: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: laravel, lumen

Tengo el siguiente error al ejecutar

`php artisan migrate`

Estoy usando Lumen 5.6

> In Connection.php line 664:
>                                                                                                                                                                                             SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users`
>   add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

---

> In Connection.php line 458:
>                                                                                                                         SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: verifica la longitud del campo email, en la tabla users al parecer esta introduciendo un valor mayor al de la longitud de tu campo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné de la siguiente forma:

Añadí las siguiente líneas de código en `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Descomente la siguiente línea de código en `bootstrap/app.php` en la línea 81;

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

Comment: a mi me salio este mensaje despues de la respuesta: Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found

Comment: Esto sucede por un cambio en el framework el cual pasa a utilizar `utf8mb4` brindando soporte a emojis y afecta a las aplicaciones que tengan una versión de MySQL menor a la *5.7.7*.

[referencia](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

Answer (score 4):

al momento de hacer tu migración, especifica la longitud en los campos de tipo unique y de tipo index, del modo siguiente:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email', 30)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Como notas con una coma le paso una longitud máxima de 30 caracteres a dicha columna con eso se debería solucionar

> Como nota te comento que eso se corrige tambien actualizando el mysql
>   a la versión 5.7; pero ojo eso se hace solo si tienes respaldo de tu
>   base de datos ya que en caso contrario puedes perderlo todo

Answer (score 0):

Ami me funciono de la siguiente manera

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id', 255);
        $table->string('name',255);
        $table->string('email',255)->unique();
        $table->string('password',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('role',100)->default('user');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB'; // !! Aquii  

    });
}
```

solo coloque la unidad referencia (engine 'InnoDB') y le definí la longitud a cada propiedad de Blueprint

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, al usar Versión MySQL   10.1.45-MariaDB-cll-lve, el problema lo tenía en la base y no en el código, el error básicamente dice que si la clave es única el campo no puede exceder cierta cantidad de caracteres, achique la cantidad, y funcionó.