# Error al migrar tablas

Tags: laravel

buenas tardes a todos en stackoverflow!

Comento el siguiente problema:

Al momento de ejecutar el comando "php artisan migrate" me lanza el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he modificado el appServiceProvider en la sección boot

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

he buscado en línea sobre este error, todos apuntan a que debo actualizar esto, poner Schema::defaultStringLength(191), pero no me sirve, me sigue tirando ese error, que podría intentar para solucionarlo?

Comment: Puede ser tambien como esta definida la collation y el engine de la BD, mira la [segunda respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160805/error-de-laravel-1071-specified-key-was-too-long), o [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159624/error-sqlstate42000) tambien hay otras posibilidades

Comment: que base de datos utilizas? cual version? como esta definido el campo permission?

Comment: pon el error como texto, no como imagen

Answer (score 1):

tu error es que laravel está intentando poner un nombre a una key demasiado largo (esto lo hace automático y la validación también).

Esto es lo que dice la documentación oficial (en inglés):

> When creating an index, Laravel will automatically generate an index name based on the table, column names, and the index type, but you may pass a second argument to the method to specify the index name yourself.

Para que no te salte en la migracion pon esto:

```
$table->unique('TuTabla', 'unique_TuTabla');
```

Más información en la [doc oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#creating-indexes)